# Sorting RDD by key

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, rdd

***Spark 2.0.1***

I have some rdd:

```
class MyClass{ }

JavaRDD<MyClass> rdd = //new hadoop api file;
Comparator<MyClass> comp;

//create comparator and do some map on the rdd

rdd.mapToPait(l -> new Tuple2<>(l , ""))
.sortByKey(comp)
.mapToPair(l -> new Tuple2<>(l._1, NullWritable.get())
.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(somePath, AvroKey.class, NullWritable.class, SomeOutputFormat.class, hadoopConfiguration);
```

And this all works very unusual to me. The application consists of 2 jobs which looks as:

[image]
[image]

The strange thing here is on ***Job 0*** we do `newAPIHadoopFile -> map -> map -> sortByKey` and that ok.

But on the ***Job 1*** we do the same (`Job1::stage1` is not skipping) and then sort and then save. Stage 2 takes lots of time. Why is that happening? Is there a way to fix the execution plan somewhere to more optimal?